# DTD XML parsing

Tags: xml-parsing, dtd, dtd-parsing, xml

If I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE country[
<!ELEMENT country
(president | king | (king,queen) | queen)>
<!ELEMENT president (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT king (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT queen (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

Why `(president | king | (king,queen) | queen)>` generate the following error if we try to validate
`<country><king>Luis</king></country>`
we get the error message `[...]Both 1st and 2nd occurence of "king" are possible`. What if I write: `(president | (king) | (king,queen) | queen)>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your content model is non-deterministic. This means that given the `king` element, the parser cannot determine which model is being matched without looking ahead. See [Deterministic Content Models (Non-Normative)](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#determinism) for more details.

What I would do is make `queen` optional when a `king` is present:

```
<!ELEMENT country (president | (king,queen?) | queen)>
```

---

**Response to comment...**

> The XML processor cannot use "look ahead" in order to figure out what is gonna "happen" after matching "king", right?

Right. For example, lets say we have this `country` element:

```
<country>
  <king/>
</country>
```

and we declare `country` like this in our DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT country (president | king | (king,queen) | queen)>
```

there are 4 possible options for the content of `country`:

1. one "president"
2. one "king"
3. one "king" followed by one "queen"
4. one "queen"

So if we have a `king` element in our XML, the parser doesn't know if it is option #2 or option #3.

If we declare `country` like this:

```
<!ELEMENT country (president | (king,queen?) | queen)>
```

there are 3 possible options for the content of `country`:

1. one "president"
2. one "king" followed by zero or one "queen"
3. one "queen"

As you can see, if we have a `king` element in our XML there is only one possible option that the parser can choose.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. The XML processor cannot use "look ahead" in order to figure out what is gonna "happen" after matching "king", right?

Comment: @bogALT - I added more explanation to my answer. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Yes. It helped. Thank you.